# Using a Back Ground worker in VB.Net WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, event-dispatch-thread

I'm new to WPF and the whole threading format. I'm pretty sure I'm close to getting this correct, however, I'm getting the error. "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." I was getting this error before and i had to add the "Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() LoadLoad())" line, but I'm still getting the error. When i get the error, it highlights the line "Dim dc = New VSCSystemEntities1" in the LoadLoad() sub method. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    InitialLoad()

End Sub

Private Sub InitialLoad()

    Try

        loadPayeeTransactionAccounts()

        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
        AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Atlas Error while Loading", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error)
    Finally

    End Try

End Sub

 Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

    LoadLoad()

End Sub

Private Sub LoadLoad()

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() LoadLoad())

    txtSearch.Text = ""

    Dim dc = New VSCSystemEntities1

    Dim ContainsSearch = New List(Of tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2)


    Try

        ContainsSearch = (From z In dc.tblActgPayeeTransactionAccounts2 Select z Where z.intActgAcctID <> 236).ToList

        For Each item In (ContainsSearch)
            For i = 1 To ContainsSearch.Count

                aList.add(New PayeeTransactions() With {.AccountingAccountID = item.intActgAcctID, .ProgramCode = item.chrPgmCode, _
                                                   .CarrierCode = item.intCarrierCode, .DealerNumber = item.chrDlrNum, _
                                                         .CoverageCode = item.chrCvgCode, .PayeeType = item.chrPayeeType, .FeeType = item.chrFeeType, .PayeeCode = item.intPayeeCode.ToString, _
                                                         .TransactionType = item.chrTransType, .AccountID = item.inbAcctgID, _
                                                         .CarrierDescription = item.chrCarrierDesc, .CarrierDescriptionShort = item.chrCarrierDescSht, _
                                                        .AccountCustomerID = item.intAcctCustID.ToString, .AccountCode = item.intAcctCo, _
                                                         .AccountCodeReceived = item.intAcctCoRec})
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
                bw.ReportProgress(i)
            Next
        Next

        lblCount.Content = ContainsSearch.Count()
        dGrid.ItemsSource = Nothing
        _ContainsText = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(aList)
        dGrid.ItemsSource = _ContainsText

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Error: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        dc.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Me.tbProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() & "%"
End Sub

Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Cancelled = True Then
        Me.tbProgress.Text = "Canceled!"
    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.tbProgress.Text = "Error: " & e.Error.Message
    Else
        Me.tbProgress.Text = "Done!"
    End If
End Sub

 Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click

    If Not bw.IsBusy = True Then
        bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You're calling the `LoadLoad` method recursively. I guess you need a return statement after `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() LoadLoad())`

Comment: There are another problems too. You're not at all making use of `BackgroundWorker` IMO you don't need it at all, or you may need to use it properly(I mean you need to make use of DoWork event with BW). Another problem is that you're sleeping in UI thread which is a bad thing to do.